# Refresh page when its required

Tags: asp.net

I am working on system for airport which displays departure, arrival and counter information.

The system will have 2 design (Desktop for operators, web based for displaying the information).

Question:

How do I refresh or load data from database when its required, or when its changed.

For Example:
In a day maximum number of flights (Departure) is 25 and operator feeds the records into database each morning and when there is a change in the flight they change the status of the flight to **Checking-in** or **Taking-off** or **Cancel**.

How do I refresh a page when there is a change in the database, Is there anyway to work with NetworkStream/TCP Clients.

Technologies: Anything is fine, and I planing to use ASP.NET.

I am thinking to use jQuery.ajax to check and refresh/update the screens.

**EDIT**
My application will run on Windows Server 2003 (Server Side) and Windows XP (Client Side) + IE6 for web interface.

Thanks

Comment: Check out SignalR (asp.net implementation of WebSockets)

Comment: Signalr or WCF which you can host with TCP/IP Also

Comment: I can't use SignalR because I am using IE6.